# jQuery .off isn't working with .on

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery accordion box that contains a right arrow to the right of each link. When the user clicks on the link, the arrow turns into a down arrow and the content expands. When the user clicks on the same link, the arrow turns back into the right arrow and the content is hidden (typical accordion style). To get the arrows to switch, I am using jQuery .on and switching out a class on a span element. Everything works just fine expect when I try to remove the event with .off. Here is my script:

```
<script>
function handleClick(event) {
    $('#arrow').removeClass('icon-angle-right').addClass('icon-angle-down');
};

$('.panel-heading a').on('click', handleClick);
$('.panel-heading a').off('click', handleClick);
</script>
```

Right now, nothing works. If I remove the .off line than the span will switch classes but obviously not switch back when clicked again.

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle for this ? will help debugging the issue

Comment: This script won't do a thing, since you bind and unbind it straight away.

Comment: The problem is the code inside the click handler. It needs to set the appropriate class depending on the open close state. $.off just unbinds the click handler

Answer (score 2):

By unbinding the event handler, you're not achieving what you want. Because you're binding the click handler then immediately unbinding it which is why nothing works if you keep the line in. You need to be running the handler every time to change out the class, the handler is what modifies the DOM, and it needs to do that both in expanding and contracting the accordion.

[`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) will successfully do what you're looking to achieve., so remove the `off()` line and switch out your function for:

```
function handleClick(event) {
    $('#arrow').toggleClass('icon-angle-right').toggleClass('icon-angle-down');
};
```

As another note, I would have a default state that would be with the arrow angled right for that item, then an `open` class I would toggle that would override the default state. That way you're only maintaining one class. But that's an architecture nitpick.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are trying to remove the handler again. Would it mot make more sense to do something like this:

```
<script>

$('.panel-heading a').on('click', function() {
     if ($(this).hassClass('icon-angle-right') {
          $(this).removeClass('icon-angle-right').addClass('icon-angle-down');
     } else {
          $(this).addClass('icon-angle-right').removeClass('icon-angle-down');
     }
});
</script>
```

Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Answer (score 0):

.on() binds an event and .off() unbinds it. See http://api.jquery.com/off/